# getting a proper value from an array at specified index

Tags: java, arrays, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm creating a game in Slick2D.
First, let me show you the GUI state where I'm stuck.

> http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/593/4v3v.jpg/

So, I have a problem in a class SettingsUI, with increasing/decreasingValue methods, whenever I call increase/decrease method, to choose value from an array, what happens when I press increase arrow button, instead of giving me (i+1) value, which is a value {1000, 700} width/height, loop iterates to the last value which is {1400, 900}. Same happens in reversed, when I'm decreasing it goes to the zero element, which is by default {800, 600}.
And what I have found out (by printing values), when I click on that arrow button, it prints like 30 times that value from just ONE click. 
I have tried to add a statement break, when I increase/decrease, inside a loop, 
but doesn't work.
So could you tell me, how can I get this to work properly, what should I add/change?

SettingsUI.clas

```
public class SettingsUI implements UIConstants {

    private PText menuTitle;
    private PText optionTitle;

    private static final int VIDEO_ROWS = 3;
    private static final int AUDIO_ROWS = 2;
    private static final int TOTAL_COLS = 2;

    private PButton[][] videoButtons = new PButton[VIDEO_ROWS][TOTAL_COLS];
    private PButton[][] audioButtons = new PButton[AUDIO_ROWS][TOTAL_COLS];

    private static final int BLOCK_X_SPACING = 40;
    private static final int BLOCK_Y_SPACING = 50;

    private static final String ARROW_LEFT_RES = "res/gui/button_arrow_left.png";
    private static final String ARROW_RIGHT_RES = "res/gui/button_arrow_right.png";

    public SettingsUI() throws SlickException {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() throws SlickException {
        this.menuTitle = new PText(BASE_COLOR, 34, false);
        this.optionTitle = new PText(BASE_COLOR, 22, false);

        for (int row = 0; row < VIDEO_ROWS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < TOTAL_COLS; col++) {
                switch (col) {
                    case 0:
                        videoButtons[row][col] = new PButton(ARROW_LEFT_RES, null);
                        continue;
                    case 1:
                        videoButtons[row][col] = new PButton(ARROW_RIGHT_RES, null);
                        continue;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < AUDIO_ROWS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < TOTAL_COLS; col++) {
                switch (col) {
                    case 0:
                        audioButtons[row][col] = new PButton(ARROW_LEFT_RES, null);
                        continue;
                    case 1:
                        audioButtons[row][col] = new PButton(ARROW_RIGHT_RES, null);
                        continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) throws SlickException {
        Input input = container.getInput();
        int mx = input.getMouseX();
        int my = input.getMouseY();

        // case width/height
        if (videoButtons[0][0].contains(mx, my)) {
            if (videoButtons[0][0].isButtonPressed(input)) {
                decreaseValue();
            }
        } else if (videoButtons[0][1].contains(mx, my)) {
            if (videoButtons[0][1].isButtonPressed(input)) {
                increaseValue();
            }
        }
        /*
        for (int row = 0; row < VIDEO_ROWS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < TOTAL_COLS; col++) {
                if (videoButtons[row][col].contains(mx, my)) {
                    if (!videoButtons[row][col].isButtonPressed(input)) continue;
                    System.out.println("row: " + row + " / col: " + col);
                    switch (col) {
                        case 0:
                            decreaseValue();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            increaseValue();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < AUDIO_ROWS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < TOTAL_COLS; col++) {
                if (audioButtons[row][col].contains(mx, my)) {
                    if (!audioButtons[row][col].isButtonPressed(input)) continue;
                    switch (col) {
                        case 0:
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        */
    }

    // temp
    private static final int[][] screen_size = {
            {800, 600},
            {1000, 700},
            {1200, 800},
            {1400, 900}
    };
    private void increaseValue() {
        for (int i = 0; i < screen_size.length; i++) {
            if (screen_size[i][0] == Settings.Video.getWidth() && screen_size[i][1] == Settings.Video.getHeight()) {
                if (i < screen_size.length - 1) {
                    Settings.Video.setWidth(screen_size[i+1][0]);
                    Settings.Video.setHeight(screen_size[i+1][1]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("WIDTH SIZE: " + Settings.Video.getWidth() + " / HEIGHT SIZE: " + Settings.Video.getHeight());

    }
    private void decreaseValue() {
        for (int i = 0; i < screen_size.length; i++) {
            if (screen_size[i][0] == Settings.Video.getWidth() && screen_size[i][1] == Settings.Video.getHeight()) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    Settings.Video.setWidth(screen_size[i-1][0]);
                    Settings.Video.setHeight(screen_size[i-1][1]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("WIDTH SIZE: " + Settings.Video.getWidth() + " / HEIGHT SIZE: " + Settings.Video.getHeight());
    }

    // temp
    private static String[][] VIDEO_ORDER = {
            {"FRAME SIZE", String.valueOf(Settings.Video.getWidth() + " x " + Settings.Video.getHeight())}, 
            {"FULL SCREEN", String.valueOf(Settings.Video.isFullscreen())},
            {"FPS", String.valueOf(Settings.Video.isFps())}
    };
    private static String[][] AUDIO_ORDER = {
            {"TURN SOUND", String.valueOf(Settings.Audio.isSound())}, 
            {"VOLUME", String.valueOf(Settings.Audio.getVolume())}
    };

    public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        int x = CONTAINER_CENTER_X / 2 - 15;
        int y = CONTAINER_MAX_Y / 6 + 40;

        menuTitle.renderText("VIDEO:", g, x, y);
        for (int row = 0; row < VIDEO_ROWS; row++) {
            renderBlock(g, optionTitle, videoButtons, VIDEO_ORDER[row][0], VIDEO_ORDER[row][1], x, y, row);
        }

        x = CONTAINER_CENTER_X / 2 - 15;
        y = CONTAINER_CENTER_Y + 40;

        menuTitle.renderText("AUDIO:", g, x, y);
        for (int row = 0; row < AUDIO_ROWS; row++) {
            renderBlock(g, optionTitle, audioButtons, AUDIO_ORDER[row][0], AUDIO_ORDER[row][1], x, y, row);
        }
    }

    private void renderBlock(Graphics g, PText optionTitle, PButton[][] buttons, String option, String value, int x, int y, int row) throws SlickException {
        x += BLOCK_X_SPACING;
        y += BLOCK_Y_SPACING;

        optionTitle.renderText(option, g, x, y + (BLOCK_Y_SPACING * row));

        for (int col = 0; col < TOTAL_COLS; col++) {
            int bx = x + x - BLOCK_X_SPACING + (BLOCK_X_SPACING * col + (x * col));
            int by = y - 10 + (row * BLOCK_Y_SPACING);

            buttons[row][col].renderImage(g, bx, by);
        }

        x = x + x + BLOCK_X_SPACING + 25;
        y = y + (BLOCK_Y_SPACING * row);

        optionTitle.renderText(value, g, x, y);
    }

}
```

SettingsScreenState.class

```
public class SettingsScreenState extends BasicGameState implements UIConstants {

    public static final int ID = 5;
    private SettingsUI settingsUI;
    private Image titleImage;
    private PButton backButton;

    @Override
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game) throws SlickException {
        this.settingsUI = new SettingsUI();
        this.titleImage = new Image("res/gui/title_settings.png");
        this.backButton = new PButton("res/gui/button_back.png", "res/gui/button_back_hover.png");
    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        RandomUtility.bgTheme(container, g);

        g.drawImage(titleImage, 50, 50);
        this.settingsUI.render(container, g);
        this.backButton.renderImage(g, CONTAINER_CENTER_X - backButton.getWidth() / 2, CONTAINER_MAX_Y - backButton.getHeight() - 30);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, int delta) throws SlickException {
        Input input = container.getInput();
        int mx = input.getMouseX();
        int my = input.getMouseY();

        this.settingsUI.update(container, delta);

        if (backButton.contains(mx, my)) {
            if (backButton.isButtonPressed(input)) {
                game.enterState(StartScreenState.ID, new FadeOutTransition(), new FadeInTransition());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

PButton.class

```
public boolean contains(int x, int y) throws SlickException {
    int minX = this.x;
    int minY = this.y;
    int maxX = this.x + image.getWidth();
    int maxY = this.y + image.getHeight();

    if ((x > minX && x < maxX) && (y > minY && y < maxY)) {
        if (hoverImage != null) {
            image = new Image(hoverImage);
        }
        return true;
    }
    image = new Image(normalImage);
    return false;
}

public boolean isButtonPressed(Input input) throws SlickException {
    return input.isMouseButtonDown(Input.MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON);
}
```

So, this is the code where is a problem:

```
public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) throws SlickException {
        Input input = container.getInput();
        int mx = input.getMouseX();
        int my = input.getMouseY();

        // case width/height
        if (videoButtons[0][0].contains(mx, my)) {
            if (videoButtons[0][0].isButtonPressed(input)) {
                decreaseValue();
            }
        } else if (videoButtons[0][1].contains(mx, my)) {
            if (videoButtons[0][1].isButtonPressed(input)) {
                increaseValue();
            }
        }
```

And this are methods, that I'm using to increase/decrease value:

```
private static final int[][] screen_size = {
            {800, 600},
            {1000, 700},
            {1200, 800},
            {1400, 900}
    };
    private void increaseValue() {
        for (int i = 0; i < screen_size.length; i++) {
            if (screen_size[i][0] == Settings.Video.getWidth() && screen_size[i][1] == Settings.Video.getHeight()) {
                if (i < screen_size.length - 1) {
                    Settings.Video.setWidth(screen_size[i+1][0]);
                    Settings.Video.setHeight(screen_size[i+1][1]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("WIDTH SIZE: " + Settings.Video.getWidth() + " / HEIGHT SIZE: " + Settings.Video.getHeight());

    }
    private void decreaseValue() {
        for (int i = 0; i < screen_size.length; i++) {
            if (screen_size[i][0] == Settings.Video.getWidth() && screen_size[i][1] == Settings.Video.getHeight()) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    Settings.Video.setWidth(screen_size[i-1][0]);
                    Settings.Video.setHeight(screen_size[i-1][1]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("WIDTH SIZE: " + Settings.Video.getWidth() + " / HEIGHT SIZE: " + Settings.Video.getHeight());
    }
```

Comment: Please a) http://sscce.org and b) at the very least if you post your code, don't  post it twice. Anyway the "print gets repeated 30 times" issue might point that you are adding to many copies of the same mouse listener, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input.isMouseButtonDown(Input.MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON)` is called on every update when the mouse button is down.

`input.isMousePressed(Input.MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON)` is called only once per mouse click.